# Stochastic integral involving Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, jump

Consider an (inhomogeneous) Poisson process $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda_t$. Then I want to compute the following integral

$\mathbb{E} \left(\int f(t,N_{t-}) d\tilde{N}_t\right)^2$

for some smooth enough function $f$ and $d\tilde{N}_t=dN-\lambda_t dt$ denotes the compensated process.

Is it true that

$$ \mathbb{E} \left(\int_0^t f(t,N_{t-}) d\tilde{N}_t\right)^2$$

$$= \mathbb{E} \int_0^t |f(t,N_{t-}) |^2 dN_t$$

$$= \mathbb{E} \int_0^t |f(t,N_{t-}) |^2 \lambda_t dt?$$

If so, then how can I prove this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
X_t=\left(\int_0^t f(s,N_{s-}) d\tilde{N}_s\right)^2
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
Y_t = \int_0^t f(s,N_{s-}) d\tilde{N}_s.
\end{align*}
By It$\hat{\text{o}}$'s product rule for jump processes (see Corollaries 11.4.10 and 11.5.5 of [this book](https://www.amazon.ca/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/0387401016/ref=sr_1_1?crid=33DU73L4670C&keywords=shreve&qid=1678144843&sprefix=shreve%2Caps%2C461&sr=8-1.)),
\begin{align*}
X_t &= 2\int_0^t Y_s dY_s + [Y, Y]_t\\
&=2\int_0^t Y_s dY_s + \sum_{0<s \le t}f(s,N_{s-})^2 (\Delta N_s)^2\\
&=2\int_0^t Y_s dY_s + \sum_{0<s \le t}f(s,N_{s-})^2 \Delta N_s\\
&=2\int_0^t Y_s dY_s + \int_0^t f(s,N_{s-})^2 dN_s\\
&=2\int_0^t Y_s dY_s + \int_0^t f(s,N_{s-})^2 d\tilde{N}_s + \int_0^t f(s,N_{s-})^2 \lambda_s ds.
\end{align*}
Given that both
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t Y_s dY_s
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t f(s,N_{s-})^2 d\tilde{N}_s
\end{align*}
are martingale, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_0^t f(s,N_{s-}) d\tilde{N}_s\right)^2 = E\left(\int_0^t f(s,N_{s-})^2 \lambda_s ds\right).
\end{align*}